# Continued Rendering Issues with Android Studio 1.4.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide, rendering

I am brand new to using Android Studio, so bear with me if this is bad.

I constantly get overlay rendering issues, no matter what API I use. I've googled quite a bit and can't really find a fix for this. The apps themselves turn out ok, but the overlay viewer does not render all the graphics properly. Here is the thing

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>   - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
>       at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
>       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)
>       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:172)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:190)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:218)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:145)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:366)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
>       at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>       at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>       at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: In the preview, what do you have set as the them?

Comment: Are you using an AppCompatTheme?